# Problemas com Chamada Post

Tags: java, jsp, post, http-request

Seguinte estou tomando o seguinte erro ao chamar um método POST

405 (Method Not Allowed)

segue o metodo que estou tentando chamar

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
  public @ResponseBody Object upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("upload() called");

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        request.setAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
        return "uploadStatus";
    }

    try {
        // for Fine Uploader delete functionality
        String qquuid = request.getParameter("qquuid");
        System.out.println("qquuid=" + qquuid);
        if (qquuid != null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(qquuid, file.getOriginalFilename());
        }
        // for Fine Uploader delete functionality ends

        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

        request.setAttribute("message", "You have successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return getSuccessMessage().toString();
}
```

e o codigo que estou usando para fazer a chamada do metodo na jsp

```
  $(function() {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        url : "sic/ito/upload",

        // Maximum file size
        max_file_size : '2mb',

        chunk_size: '1mb',

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize : {
            width : 200,
            height : 200,
            quality : 90,
            crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
        },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters : [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt,pdf"},
            {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip,avi,rar"}
        ],

        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,

        // Sort files
        sortable: true,

        // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
        dragdrop: true,

        // Views to activate
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
            active: 'thumbs'
        },

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : '/resources/plupload-2.3.1/js/Moxie.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : '/resources/plupload-2.3.1/js/Moxie.xap'
    });
});
```